# Style &gt;/&lt; signs html with css

Tags: html, css

I  want to style greater-than and less-than signs with css.

My html is like this:

```
&lt;some text more text some text&gt;
```

And I want to style the < and > signs. I know I could wrap it in a `<span>`, but could I do something like this in my stylesheet?

```
&gt; {
font-weight:bold;
font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: You would have to wrap it. Alternatively, you could also add it via the `:before`/`:after` pseudo elements and add styling.

Comment: If the only answer you are interested in is "does this work?" then why do you ask instead of just trying it out?

Comment: @AwesomeByte , which kind of style would you apply to these symbols?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/UBisEzoL/1/edit)**

```
<p class="my-class">some text more text some text<p>
```

CSS:

```
.my-class:before {
  content: '<';
  color: red;
}

.my-class:after {
  content: '>';
  color: blue;
}
```

The only other way would be to wrap with an element (preferably span) like you said. For completeness, I'll include that solution:

```
<p>
  <span class="my-class">&lt;</span>
  some text more text some text
  <span class="my-class">&gt;</span>
<p>
```

CSS:

```
.my-class {
  color: red;
}
```

If you are willing to use JavaScript, here's an example: **[Demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/UBisEzoL/3/edit)**

**Sample Markup:**

```
<p class="my-class">&lt;some text more text some text&gt;<p>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('my-class');

for (var i=0; i<elems.length; ++i) {
  var elem = elems[i];
  var childs = elem.childNodes;
  var len = childs.length;
  for (var j=0; j<len; ++j) {
    var node = childs[j];
    if (node.nodeName === '#text') {
      var text = node.textContent;
      var first = text.charAt(0);
      var last = text.charAt(text.length-1);
      if (first === '<' && last === '>') {
        text = text.split('');
        text.splice(0, 1);
        text.splice(text.length-1);
        text = text.join('');

        var left = document.createElement('span');
        left.className = 'my-span-class left';
        left.textContent = '<';

        var right = document.createElement('span');
        right.className = 'my-span-class right';
        right.textContent = '>';

        node.textContent = text;
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(left, node);
        node.parentNode.appendChild(right, node);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not really styling existing ones, that's just adding some styled ones in. I personally find that even more annoying than wrapping them in a `<span>`

Comment: @musefan My intention wasn't to say what a person should do, just what could be done. I updated with a js solution as well, if that makes you happier.

Answer (score 1):

The only means to apply CSS to a given character is with the [`:first-letter` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-letter), obviously this doesn't suit your needs.

CSS has no means to select a character based on what that character is. You will have to add additional elements if you want to style it.

Comment: Actually, @font-face **can** be limited to specific characters based on unicode. It's not supported in all browsers so I would not offer it as a solution. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-range

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to wrap your & gt & lt; signs within a span via javascript after onload (which would not work for content added afterwards dynamically). But the short answer is no, there's no content based selection on css

Answer (score 0):

Since a solution with pseudoelements was already suggested here's my approach:

if you need to use only a different `font-family` and `font-weight` (as specified in your question as example) on modern browser (supporting `unicode-range` property) you could use a different font-face for these two symbols

Example (*working on Chrome, Opera and Safari, not working on Firefox, not tested on IE*)
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KDgep

```
@font-face {
  font-family: lessgreaterthan;
  font-weight: bold;
  src: local('Arial');
  unicode-range: U+003C,U+003E;
}

p {
  font-family: lessgreaterthan, "times new roman";
}
```

Comment: I don’t think it works for the `bold` part, and I double whether it should work at all, when the declaration for `p` does not specify bold face.